# How to go between a set of dates and times

Tags: sql, datetime, between

I have a set of data where one column is date and time. I have been asked for all the data in the table, between two date ranges and within those dates, only certain time scale. For example, I was data between 01/02/2019 - 10/02/2019 and within the times 12:00 AM to 07:00 AM. (My real date ranges are over a number of months, just using these dates as an example)

I can cast the date and time into two different columns to separate them out as shown below:

```
select

name
,dateandtimetest
,cast(dateandtimetest as date) as JustDate
,cast(dateandtimetest as time) as JustTime
INTO #Test01
from [dbo].[TestTable]
```

I put this into a test table so that I could see if I could use a `between` function on the JustTime column, because I know I can do the `between` on the dates no problem. My idea was to get them done in two separate tables and perform an `inner join` to get the results I need

```
from #Test01
WHERE justtime between '00:00' and '05:00'
```

The above code will not give me the data I need. I have been racking my brain for this so any help would be much appreciated!

The test table I am using to try and get the correct code is shown below:

```
|Name       | DateAndTimeTest   
-----------------------------------------| 
|Lauren     | 2019-02-01 04:14:00   |
|Paul       | 2019-02-02 08:20:00   |
|Bill       | 2019-02-03 12:00:00   |
|Graham     | 2019-02-05 16:15:00   |
|Amy        | 2019-02-06 02:43:00   |
|Jordan     | 2019-02-06 03:00:00   |
|Sid        | 2019-02-07 15:45:00   |
|Wes        | 2019-02-18 01:11:00   |
|Adam       | 2019-02-11 11:11:00   |
|Rhodesy    | 2019-02-11 15:16:00   |
```

I have now tried and got the data to show me information between the times on one date using the below code, but now I would need to make this piece of code run for every date over a 3 month period

```
select * 

from dbo.TestTable

where DateAndTimeTest between '2019-02-11 00:00:00' and '2019-02-11 08:30:00'
```

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: I am just testing it in SQL server management studio. The real data is using SQL server 2008, I haven't actually seen it myself, I have just been asked for advice and now its taking over my every thought -_-

Comment: `between '12:00' and '05:00'` propably doesn't work because 12 > 5, you'll have to use `not between '05:00' and '12:00'`

Comment: Ive just realised the 12:00 I am using is actualy meant to be midnight, so using the logic you showed above and the logic I tried, it doesnt filter the data correctly. I can get the time to work with a between '2019-02-11 00:00:00' and '2019-02-11 08:30:00' no problem, but the issue is, i want this for a range of dates, not just the one date specified? Any ideas?

Comment: Time `12:00` is noon in sql, so you'll have to use `00:00`, have you tried this or is it just update in question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL similar to following:

```
select *
from dbo.TestTable
where (CAST(DateAndTimeTest as date) between '2019-02-11' AND '2019-02-11') AND 
      (CAST(DateAndTimeTest as time) between '00:00:00' and '08:30:00')
```

Above query will return all records where DateAndTimeTest value in date range 2019-02-11 to 2019-02-11 and with time between 12AM to 8:30AM.

Comment: Amazing that worked great! I got it working but casting them into temp tables and then joining but this is so much simpler! Thanks so much